# load url from qr code to web view swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, qr-code

hello i create a QR code reader and work great but theta open url in safari and i want to open it in my webview swift in another scene

```
if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {

    // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds

    let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds;

    if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {

        messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
        //if the result is url...
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: metadataObj.stringValue)!)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

openURL will get the device to handle the URL, unless your application has a defined URL scheme that matches the URL it will likely be passed to the web browser unless another application handles that scheme.

If you want to render it in a webView, createa a webView and pass in the URL you want to load...

```
if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {

        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds

        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds;

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {

            messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            //if the result is url...

            let url = NSURL(string: metadataObj.stringValue)!
            let request = NSURLRequest(url: url)
            webView.loadRquest(request)
        }
    }
```

I would recommend putting those let statements in a if let instead to catch any errors but thats the basic principle.

You just need to add the webView to the view

Comment: i have 2 different files web view its in *ViewController.swift*
and the qr code scanner its in *QRRViewController.swift*

Comment: i want to load from qr code(connected class QRRViewController.swift)after scanning  to show the website in webview (connected class ViewController.swift)

Comment: ok, you will need to pass the url to the view controller and dismiss your QRViewController, then load the webView contents from the URL, you may need to use a delegate function or pass in a reference to your parent view controller so that you can set this property

Comment: i find something like this bot  i don't know how can i do func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "passData") {
            let data = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController
            
            data.QRLink = messageLable.text!
        } theta docent work